# How to clear virtual memory without closing matlab?

Tags: matlab, memory

I am working on activity recognition but am getting an `out of memory error` after processing one video.

The maximum possible array turns from 444mb to 84mb, which means it can't process more than one video. Using `clear all;` and `close all;` we can just clear the matlab memory, but how do we clear the virtual memory (ram) space without closing matlab?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: 32 bit OS or 64bit? In the former case there is not much you can do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [memory not freed in matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496594/memory-not-freed-in-matlab)

Comment: 32 bit windows xp matlab 2012a. if we restart the matlab virtual memory will be cleared but i cant do that because i have to process more than 20 videos at once to create the templates.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do all of them simultaneously, there probably is not enough memory. However I assume you want to process them sequentially.
As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496594/memory-not-freed-in-matlab), you may have to resort to closing matlab and restarting it.

This may sound awfull, but with a little work you can ease the pain.

Here are steps you can take:

1. Make sure your progress is written on disk in a convenient way, for example a .mat file with the list of numbers that still need to be processed.
2. Write a wrapper function. This function should just:

   - Open the list
   - Make sure the next item from the list gets processed
   - If there is something left in the list, open a new matlab session where this function is called, and closes the existing session

The last part may not be easy to find, but suppose the function you want to call is `magic(5)`, then it would be something like this:

```
!matlab -r "magic(5)" &
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

[Java Heap Cleaner](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36757-java-heap-cleaner) seems to work fairly well. But if you try and call it after you get a "Java heap space" type of error, it may or may not help, I haven't quite figured out if there's a pattern.

**Edit**: Try also the

```
pack
```

command. That forces Matlab to run the garbage collector on its own memory, while the Java Heap Cleaner does the same thing but on the Java memory.

**Edit 2**: I found out that you don't need to download Java Heap Cleaner to run the JVM garbage collector. You can also go for:

```
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.gc;
```

That seems to work quite well for me.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but are you loading a whole video in Matlab as array? If that's the case, there might be better ways to process the video, loading it frame-by-frame.

Comment: matlab help for `pack' indicates that it should work. Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: @Ufos I find it depends on the situation, but it works. Keeping an eye on Matlab's memory usage, when I call `pack` I can see it decrease. Same goes with `java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.gc`. The latter is really only useful if the UI gets sluggish. You can use `java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.freeMemory` before and after to see the difference.

Comment: @Roberto. The problem is that they do not mention it should work only on windows. Also, despite what matlab claims, it's just defragmenting the memory, nothing else. 
http://sccn.ucsd.edu/pipermail/eeglablist/2007/001776.html

p.s. no gui involved either, I am using it in the console mode with an external editor.

Comment: @Ufos That's interesting. I can't reproduce this right now so I might have been wrong, but I was almost sure that in some circumstances `clear` didn't reduce the memory used, but calling `pack` after `clear` did. I'll let you know if I manage to get an example working. Note, _in some circumstances_ is the keyword here. Also, I was never able to get anything actually useful out of `pack`. Whenever I went out of memory, it was never for a few bytes, so these tricks didn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

If run-time is not an issue for you, you may try using `matfile` that will let you access/load/save your data on your hard drive rather than RAM, but as your would expect, the process might be slow.

Another option that I tried while working on my problem is to convert my data to `single` precision, this should reduce the memory consumption by half. For videos and images, I believe that most of the work is doable using `single` instead of `double` precision. Of course, if you could, then further using them in `uint8` will reduce the consumption by 8.

Related to your original problem, I think there is actually no solution for that other than restarting matlab everytime.